# copy and paste text from end of line

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

A long short but is there a way to copy the end of select lines and append the text to that line. What I want to achieve is this.

what I have

```
>13_gnd
atcg
>14_galF
atgc
```

what I want

```
>13_gnd_gnd
atcg
>14_galF_galF
atgc
```

So all lines starting with `>`copy the last word and append to the end of the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/_[^_]*$/&&/' file         
>13_gnd_gnd
atcg
>14_galF_galF
atgc
```

The `sed` substitution will match the last underscore on each line and whatever is after it, to the end of the line. This is what the pattern `_[^_]*$` does ("match an underscore possibly followed by other non-underscore characters, and the end of line"). It will *replace* this (including the underscore) with whatever was matched, twice (this is what `&&` does in the replacement bit).

Since this appears to be a file in [Fasta format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), and since genomic sequences can't contain underscores, no special test is needed for `>` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: As the question refers to "all lines starting with `>`" and we don't don't whether the undercore can appear in other lines, too, the safe solution would be `sed '/^>/s/_[^_]*$/&&/' file`. However, I like the `&&` replacement. (-:

Comment: @Philippos There can't be underscores on other lines. The file is a [Fasta file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), and the non-header lines (the ones not starting with `>`) can't contain underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'_' '$0~/^>/{ $0=$0 FS $NF }1' file
```

The output:

```
>13_gnd_gnd
atcg
>14_galF_galF
atgc
```

---

Details:

- `-F'_'` - field separator
- `$0~/^>/` - performs an action if the line starts with `>`
- `$0=$0 FS $NF` - appends the last field value to the end